# how to programmatically create UISplitViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I need a simple UISplitViewController to be created programmatically?
Wherever i see it is only using XIB.. so kindly provide a link or example for UISplitViewController programmatically...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UISplitViewController *c = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
c.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myVC1, myVC2, nil];
```

If you need anything more than that, you'll have to ask a better question...

Comment: This is a perfect answer jtbandes +1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. now i am able to see only the DetailViewController in Portrait mode and both in Landscape mode..Why is it happening?

Comment: That's how UISplitViewController works. I also recommend reading the iOS 5 beta release notes.

Comment: @jtbandes how can i create 2 Uitableviews in same uiview. And when i click left tableview i want to shoe another rightside UItableview. how can i create this. could you help me.